# Hardware multipliers on classic CPUs

Tags: z80, 6502, 6809

Can anyone offer some back-of-envelope sort of estimates of what sort of gate count was needed to add a multiplier to 8-bit CPUs?

I ask because I find it a bit odd that the 6809 had one, but none of the other chips of the era did. It seems that B or C models of the 6502 and Z80 would have the opportunity to add this, so I assume there is a good reason why they didn't?

Comment: I'm sure you know that some multiplications are equivalent to left shifts. And so the ARM can use a barrel shifter to multiply e.g. by 9 with a single ADD instruction. The CDC 160 could multiply by a few fixed constants (including 10 and 100 decimal) in this way, by really using an adder. But, assuming you're asking about multiplication by arbitrary factors, I don't know an answer to your question.

Comment: Multiply by shift and repeated add is mainly a question of microcode, not gate count. Now *fast* multiply is a different thing... that can eat up quite a few gates. Also, 8-bit multiply primitives are not that useful if you need wider arguments/results, so the cost/effect ratio isn't that high.

Comment: I doubt the multiplier was the limiting factor since you first have to double the size of the result register and ALU to make it worthwhile to have a hardware multiplier. And the Z80 already had almost as many transistors as the 6809 without any of its performance.

Comment: Well if we focus on the 6502 for the moment, it would seen a single new (M?) register for the upper 8 bits of the result, and a table for the shift-n-add (maybe 512 bytes in a diode array) and you have the basic thing done. You would need the microcode for the loops, but this seems like something that's not TOO large?

Comment: I don't know much about the Z80 microcode design, but 6502s microcode wasn't sophisticated enough to support that. It allowed maximum of 4 microops per instruction, IIRC, and its ability to take conditional actions was very limited. You'd have to expand the size of the so called PLA substantially to make the encoding powerful enough for a shift and add based multiply operation.

Comment: ... The 6502 PLA (having just looked it up) is 130 bits wide with 21 inputs (corresponding to 15 bits derived from the opcode and 6 time states for a maximum of 6 microops). At the very least you'd need to expand it out to allow 9 microops, so input will have to be 24 bits, and you'd need at least nine more output lines (one for each conditional add operation, and one to put your new register on the result bus). I suspect it would actually need many more than that, but can't be certain.  That's a nearly 50% increase in area.

Comment: Interesting read: http://www.cpushack.com/2017/12/19/chip-of-the-day-trw-mpy-16aj-making-multiplication-manageable/ basically, 16x16 multiply = 330ns and 3600 gates and 5W, with a yield of 3 devices per wafer.

Comment: but seriously, multiplier at that time is a very specialized equipment, like FPU, and if a processor is equipped with one, then it's a dsp. maybe it's easier to connect the multiplier as a co-processor than to integrate it into the instruction set, like MSP430?

Comment: @Jules - that's the sort of thing I was looking for!

Comment: Then it would be best if @Jules would make a formal answer.

Comment: Actually, 8051 (MCS51 family) also had both multiply and division, though latter limited to 8bit arguments and hence not very useful.

Comment: Concur with most of the comments here - A multiplier within the limited size of arguments and result registers of an 8-bit CPU is not really useful.

Comment: @tofro: Even an 8x8 multiply can be quite useful if it yields a 16-bit result, especially operands and results can efficiently be moved in and out of it.  In fact, such a multiply may be more useful than a 16x16->32 multiply that cannot exchange data as efficiently.  To be sure many chips' multipliers make things awkward; the PIC 18Fxx parts, for example, always use W for one of the operands, but put the results in PRODH:PRODL registers.  If there were a separate multiplicand register, one could perform an 8x32 (or 8xN) multiply or partial product by loading the multiplicand once, then...

Comment: ...processing the first 8 bits of the other multiplicand, store PRODL to the result and load W with PRODH, then process the next 8 bits, add W to PRODL and store it, and load W with PRODH, process the next 8 bits, add-with-carry W to PRODL, etc.  Unfortunately, things end up being rather more awkward, though not quite as bad as using individual shifts and adds.

Comment: @supercat - yes, the 8x8->16 is what I was thinking about. It would cut out the inner loops of the math libraites and offer greatly improved performance for those libs. It wouldn't even have to be fast; simply avoiding all those loads and loops (and self-modifying code tricks) would seem worthwhile.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz: It would be fairly easy to build a little bit of extra hardware to improve the performance of multiplication in a typical system without having to actually build anything so complicated as an ALU.  For example, a shifter and a 32-byte ROM wired up to the proper address pins would make it possible to have a portion of a Z80's address space contain the repeating four byte instruction sequence "[ADD B, ADC B, AND A, or RET] / RRA / RR C", with the choice of ADD, ADC, NOP, or RET for the first instruction being controlled by A5-A6 and the output of the shifter.

Comment: I may be getting the sequence slightly wrong, but the idea would be to eliminate any need for branching or looping instructions to reduce the multiply purely to a sequence of shifts and adds.  Some modern ARM microcontrollers do something very much like this to facilitate division, providing division routines in a rather large "ROM" which I suspect is actually implemented with a small amount of logic.

Comment: Note that some of the first 32-bit RISC processors did not include Multiply instructions, as the cost-benefit ratio, given typical user code and benchmarks, wasn't there.  MUL would have been even less needed in earlier technology nodes, except for special much lower volume applications such as DSP.

Comment: @supercat - that is why I asked, I was looking over algos for multiplication on the 6502 and it seemed one could implement it in hardware. Doing so would avoid a **lot** of looping. So that's why I thought I was missing some key element of the concept, but it appears I was not, the complexity isn't all that bad?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can anyone offer some back-of-envelope sort of estimates of what sort of gate count was needed to add a multiplier to 8-bit CPUs?

An 8x8 array multiplier build from 6T adders comes down to 8x8x6=384 transistors. With buffers/drivers this easily reaches beyond 400 transistors, maybe even near 600 when latching is needed.  Further some decoding (PLA) and execution (random) might be needed, but that's just a few dozen transistors. In total this might increase the CPU by 20%.

The operation needs two 8 bit values as input and yields one 16 bit value. For a 6502 input would be naturally `A` and a memory operand, but there is no 16 bit register. While storing the lower 8 bits again in `A`might sound useful, `X` or `Y` could take the upper 8 bits - damaging the ability to use either in addressing. Or a new `E`xtension register would be needed. Not a bad idea in general (*1), but that adds something like another 50 transistors (*2).

> I ask because I find it a bit odd that the 6809 had one, but none of the other chips of the era did.

The 6809 is a complete new design, and the next generation after a 6800 or 6502, more in line with upcoming 16-bit processors of the same time.

> It seems that B or C models of the 6502 and Z80 would have the opportunity to add this,

These were just faster speed selections, not really new (or enhanced) CPUs.

> so I assume there is a good reason why they didn't?

As so often it's the 'why' question. Why adding and complicating the CPU for such a minor add on? Sure, it'll speed up multiplying, but then again, it's not exactly the most needed operation. I can't remember having it used in all the years of 8086 programming. And even on /370 it was convenient, but not really necessary. Usually, multiplying by 2 or 4 is what's needed, and here a shift will always beat a multiply.

---

*1 - This might open the opportunity for some quite nice new operations, not at least 16 bit load and store, enabling fast movement of pointers (into ZP).

*2 - Renesas for example did not only add an 8x8 multiply and divide instruction to their 6502 (740 Family), but also avoided the addition of a new register by pushing the upper 8 bits of the multiplication result onto the stack - similarly, with a division, the negated(!) remainder is pushed.

Comment: You're forgetting that you'll need 64 AND gates as well.

Comment: @LeoB. For what? A 6T full adder just needs said 6 transistors.

Comment: For ANDing one multiplicand with one bit of the other before adding the result to the partial sum.

Comment: Using the [Dadda tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dadda_multiplier) multiplicand reduction, you start with the output of the 64 AND gates, then apply full or half adders in a way to minimize their total count. That way you'll need 64 AND gates, 49 full adders and 7 half adders.

Comment: That's assuming that none of the gates and adders were fused using pass-transistor logic, very commonly done back in the multi-phase-clock NMOS days.

Comment: Adding another register also means an additional mux to bring it out to the alu result bus (presuming you'll want a `TEA` instruction to copy it to the accumulator, and presumably also `STE`), so add another 16 transistors for that, plus an extra output from the PLA to control it.

Comment: @Jules do we need an extra output from the PLA? Seems like it could repurpose whatever's responsible for undefined opcodes `SAX` and `LAX`.

Comment: @Wilson - the undefined opcodes don't have any specific outputs from the PLA, they just trigger effectively random existing lines, which is why they have behaviour that's similar to existing instructions.  New behaviour, like triggering a read of a specific register, would need a new output.  And because the PLA's structure only allows you to make outputs an OR of input signals, you may also need to add additional outputs that effectively disable other outputs in order to prevent other actions happening by default for the opcode you've chosen for any new instruction.

Comment: @Wilson not realy, as the undefined opcode behaviour is exactly due being not defined. For new opcodes, the existing might need new or at least modified columns to open up the 'undefined' space, and then there are the ones needed for the new opcodes. So yes, it would need a few more connections. Anywhere between 1 and like 5 per new instruction.

Comment: @Jules The register to bus connection aren't multiplexers, just tristate buffers. Further, they are already included in the rough estimation of 50 transistors. Give or talke a few, it's a ballpark number to see the magnitude we are talking.

Comment: "These where just faster seed selections" - I know, but that's the basis of the question. If you had two Moore's-laws to work with, perhaps one can think of better things to do than solely a die shrink. Your answer, and the comments following, suggest such a think *was* possible, but simply not interesting to the marker they were attacking.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz Oops, that should read speed.  And yes, that's what I wanted to point out with the last paragraph. In fact, there have been many enhanced 6502 made. Starting with Rockwells CMOS. This even includes several with multiplication instructions. For example Renesas 740/75xx family which did include multiply operation (Or Rockwell with a dual core:)). Except, non of these CPUs where picked up by mainstream (desktop) computers.

Answer (score 6):

The first production 6809 was fabricated around 3 years after the first production 6502, and thus, according to the Moore's Law rate of transistor density improvements, was likely fabricated using a small enough transistor geometry that more than double the number the number of transistors were available for the same initial die yield and cost, thus allowing room for adding multiply logic to the ALU (9k, vs. around 4k transistors per die).

A fast carry-save-adder (CSA) tree implementation (e.g. not just a microcoded shift-and-add) of an 8x8to16-bit multiplier requires (I'm guessing) roughly on the order of 5 times as many transistors as an 8-bit adder.  In NMOS technology of that vintage, a CSA-type multiplier implementation would very possibly not be done using strictly complete logic "gates", but by also using a mix of pass transistor logic plus inverting amplifiers, even thru to the end of the final carry chain.

No reason to add a mul instruction to later versions of the 6502 and Z80 (even if fabricated in a denser more advanced technology node), since software compatibility and cost reduction was the name of the game for those products.

Comment: Is your guess about *roughly on the order of 5 times* a substantiated one?

Comment: Best way to find out is to try to find the multiplier in a die photo of a 6809.